# AutoMapper: Mapping child collections

Tags: c#, automapper

AutoMapper Newbie Question.

I have a source and destination DTO that have the same fields and child collections. How can AutoMapper map these?

Simplified source and destination DTOs share the same names:

> ```
> Customer
>     Orders
>        Invoices
>     CustomerInfo
> ```

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should map child collections automatically provided you have maps for each of the types. (`Order`, `Invoice`, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Orders, OrderModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Invoices, InvoicesModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerInfo, CustomerInfoModel>();
var mappedModel = Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerModel>(customer);
```

here is another similar topic: [AutoMapper - mapping child collections in viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270396/automapper-mapping-child-collections-in-viewmodel)

Comment: this fails when sub object is null. how to handle it?