# Automapper: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[DataObjects.BookEntity]' to type 'DataObjects.BookEntity

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, automapper

Please see the code below:

```
Public Function GetBook(ByVal ISBN As Integer) As Book Implements IBookDAO.GetBook
        Using context = New LibraryDBEntities()
            'Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Where(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
            Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Where(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)

            Dim details = Mapper.Map(Of BookEntity, Book)(bookDetails)
            Return details
        End Using
    End Function
```

The error I get is: "{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[DataObjects.BookEntity]' to type 'DataObjects.BookEntity'."}" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created map configuration for your source and destination types ??

Comment: @gaurav, they are in the constructor.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722491/using-automapper-to-map-ilisttsource-to-iesi-collections-generic-isettdesti

Comment: I think you might need Mapper.Map(Of IEnumerable(Of BookEntity),IEnumerable(of Book)(bookDetails)..Sorry if my VB stinks here...IT has been a while