# ASP.NET MVC4 AutoMapper: Loses mapping when reach a Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have a strange situation that I cannot figure out. I have a simple ASP.NET MVC4 application and am using AutoMapper to move data between ViewModel and Entity (DB) objects.

The issue that I am fighting is that my configuring of AutoMapper in `Application_Start()` seems to disappear when I reach `Create()` in CustomerController.

If I invoked Configure in the `Create()` method, the mapping from CustomerViewModel to CustomerEntity works properly.

I have scoured the Internet and have not seen anyone reporting this issue, so hopefully someone can give me a clue.  Here are the details... I hope that someone has some suggestions because it is driving me crazy! :P

In global.asax.cs, in `Application_Start()`, I call the configure() method on my class:

```
AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure();
```

Here is the class:

```
public class AutoMapperConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure() 
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<AutoMappingProfile>()); 
    }
}
```

AutomMappingProfile is my AutoMapper profile class.  It is implemented, as follows:

```
public class AutoMappingProfile : Profile    

    public override string ProfileName        
    {          
        get { return "AutoMappingProfile";}     
    }       

    protected override void Configure()  
    {
        CreateMaps();  
    }

    private void CreateMaps()  
    {
        CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerEntity>();
        CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, CustomerViewModel>();
        CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, CustomerEntity>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();

        CreateMap<CustomerVendorProductEntity, CustomerVendorProductEntity>();
        CreateMap<CustomersVendorsProductViewModel, CustomersVendorsProductViewModel>();
        CreateMap<CustomerVendorProductEntity, CustomersVendorsProductViewModel>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
        CreateMap<CustomersVendorsProductViewModel, CustomerVendorProductEntity>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
    } 
}
```

I set a breakpoint on `CreateMaps()` and see that it is invoked when the application starts.

When I invoke an action to create a new Customer entity, the Create() method in CustomerController is invoked.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, CustomerViewModel vm)
    {
    .
    .
    var customer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel, CustomerEntity>(vm);
    .
    .   
}
```

The mapping always fails with a `NotSupportedException` on the mapping from a List to a Collection.

I have implemented  ListSourceMapper, which is loaded as a Mapper in Configure().  I don't show it here, because it works...  The issue that I am fighting is that my configuring of AutoMapper in Application_Start() seems to disappear when I reach Create() in CustomerController.  If I invoked Configure in the Create() method, the mapping from CustomerViewModel to CustomerEntity works properly.  I have scoured the Internet and have not seen anyone reporting this issue, so hopefully someone can give me a clue.

Comment: well, it seems correct (I may have missed something), but there's a strange thing in your mapping, with your maps between same entities... (like `CreateMap<CustomerEntity, CustomerEntity>();`)

Comment: can you show your ListSourceMapper as well please?

Comment: Anything to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483174/map-ilist-to-icollection-through-automapper ? Are you trying to map *TO* an `ICollection<T>` ? AM doesnt support that directly as it OOTB doesnt guess concrete counterparts for abstract types - are you sure it's completely deterministic as long as you call the init in the `Create` method?. What happens if you do an AssertValid on the configuration?

Comment: You should also add a call to `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` at the end of AutoMapperConfigurator.Configure().

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've just started my first MVC4 project and am getting the same issue (have used AutoMapper previously in MVC3 without any issues).

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, but it only occurs very sporadically on our production server. We have not been able to reproduce on Dev, UAT or Staging.  Prod mostly works fine, but every now and again the mappings, configured like yours in `Application_Start()`, will get "lost" and a `NotSupportedException` continues to be thrown from the mapping calls in our controller methods, until we recycle the app pool.  Note that the start of a period of errors does not itself seem to coincide with an app pool recycle - at the moment we can see no pattern to it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same in an ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET 4.0) project. It seems like it "forgets" about the mapping, because if I put in the CreateMap code in my Action on my Controller, the exact same code works fine. So both my CreateMap and my Map code is fine it seems... pretty frustrating...

Comment: Ok, I found the solution to my problem...I had a class with the same name in a different namespace....mapped the wrong one.....stupid me - AutoMapper works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this last year, which I described here:

[ASP.NET MVC4 AutoMapper: Loses mapping when reach a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813590/asp-net-mvc4-automapper-loses-mapping-when-reach-a-controller)

I had a controller, which had the following constructor:

```
 IApplicationDAO applicationDAO = new ApplicationDAO();
 public ApplicationController()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<ApplicationModel, BusinessObjects.Application>();
            });
```

and a data object, which had the following constructor:

```
public ApplicationDAO()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<BusinessObjects.Application, DataObjects.dbApplication>()
                   .ReverseMap();
            });
        }
```

The data object is created once and called multiple times by the constructor.  Each time the data object is called by the constructor it overwrites the mappings set in ApplicationDAO meaning AutoMapper always produced an error.

The solution for me was to ensure all mappings are created in the composition root i.e. Global.asax.